# Can I ask software specific questions here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I am a new Linux (Ubuntu) user and I would like to ask about how to do certain things with popular applications like LMMS.

Can I ask these types of questions here?

I don't know how popular the site http://www.linuxquestions.org is, but I have seen plenty of people asking questions about LMMS there. However, I would prefer to ask on a Stack Exchange site for all the obvious reasons.

Example question: 'How can I disable the metronome when recording from LMMS'

Answer (score 3):

That's perfectly fine. After all, most questions are specific to some piece of software somehow!

You may prefer to ask on the [Unix and Linux site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) - it's completely up to you though.

Comment: I would say for a desktop user oriented software you are much more likely to get a better answer on askubuntu.